# Can reagent components have more than one top level HTML entities?

Tags: clojure, reagent

I seen plenty of code like this:

```
(defn simple-component []
  [:div
   [:p "I am a component!"]
   [:p "This component has two paragraphs"]])
```

Is there a way to make that component have just two p elements, without the enclosing div?

Comment: have you tried `[ [:p .. ] [:p .. ] ]` ?

Comment: @birdspider that doesn't work, as the firs item in a vector is the element name, and there, the first item of the vector is another vector.

Comment: how about a list `(list [:p .. ] [:p .. ] )` - since it uses hiccup syntax and vectors seem to have a special meaning, also: https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/blob/1.0.5/src/hiccup/compiler.clj#L234

Comment: List does not work

Answer (score 1):

it seems "rookie mistake".
please check this wiki page: Form-1: A Simple Function
https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components

Comment: I already read that page and it shows how to do it with a surrounding div. I'm asking how to do it *without* a surrounding div. Something that I remember being possible with hiccup.

Comment: I think we need div. Reaget can use Hiccup-like markup, not Hiccup, just "like".

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a react fragment which can created in two ways:

1. With a js array (which takes react elements):

   ```
   (defn simple-component []
         #js [(r/as-element [:p "I am a component!"])
              (r/as-element [:p "This component has two paragraphs"])])
   ```
2. With the `[:<> ... ]` tag (which takes hiccup forms):

   ```
   (defn simple-component []
         [:<>
             [:p "I am a component!"]
             [:p "This component has two paragraphs"]])
   ```

[Implemented in this PR](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/pull/352/files#diff-17453196983b87ab1421488f4680e353R1134)